# Ruby on Rails: Difference between behaviour within the console / in a .rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to use information stored within a the `credentials.yml.enc` file for a Rails 5.2 app.  However, I am struggling to get a command which works perfectly within the console to behave in the same way when inserted into a `.rb` file.

In the Rails console (on my local development computer) `Rails.application.credentials.username` returns `"my_username"`

If I insert this line within a very simple `db_backup.rb` file as shown below, I get the error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant #<Class:#<Backup::Config::DSL:0x00007fb0db941d10>>::Rails
```

`db_backup.rb`:

```
Model.new(:db_backup, 'Description for db_backup') do
  ##
  # PostgreSQL [Database]
  #
  database PostgreSQL do |db|
    db.username           = Rails.application.credentials.username
  end
end
```

**Please could you explain why I get the different behaviour when using exactly the same line of code in the Rails console / within a `.rb` file?**

Comment: Where is the `db_backup.rb` file? Is it part of your Rails app, or on its own? How are you executing it?

Comment: It was automatically created in a folder which was in the root directory on my laptop, I moved this manually to within the Rails app's Config folder.  I am running it using `$ backup perform --trigger my_backup --config-file /path/to/config.rb`.  If I hard-code the value, rather than trying to read from the `credentials` file, the entire script works fine (and when adding in the other lines required I can successfully make a backup).  It's literally swapping the hardcoded value to a statement which works fine in the console that raises the error

Comment: Rails console loads all your app, a single .rb file is just plain Ruby. If you want custom scripts to have access to all your Rails app, use a rake task. Then you will be able to do `rake backup ....` and do whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks for your input, its really started to help me get to grips with this.  If i create a really simple rake file and define the `task` as `ruby 'db_backup.rb',` i get the error `NameError: uninitialized constant Model`.  My understanding is that there are disadvantages to installing the `backup` gem via the `gem file` and instead it should be installed outside of the application.  Do you have a view on how to get around this?  Does it mean I need to read the contents of `credentials.yml.enc` into the `db_backup.rb` script somehow? Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by simply adding the line below to the top of my `db_backup.rb`:

```
require './config/environment'  # added to enable credentials to be read from Rails environment
```

Answer (score 3):

The context in which the code is executed is not the same. One is the rails console and the other is the backup command

### What happens when you load the Rails console

Launching the rails console means you launch all of the rails stack before executing your code against it. The Rack applications like Sinatra, Rails etc. use the `config.ru` file as a convention for which file should be run to boot. (You can explore the rabbit hole if you want to have a deep understanding of this)

It means that the vast majority of errors you can encounter when will occur during the console boot, preventing you from executing anything in the console (because boot failed). Instead it will print the stack trace errors for you to figure out what went wrong so you can correct and give it another try.

TL; DR `Rails.application.credentials.username` in console is executed **after all of the Rails stack (models, dependencies, initializers) has loaded in a particular order**

### What happens when you run the backup command

The `backup` command is defined here [in the bin repo of the backup repo](https://github.com/backup/backup/blob/master/bin/backup)

It goes like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

require File.expand_path("../../lib/backup", __FILE__)
Backup::CLI.start
```

If you open the required file `lib/backup.rb` and look around in the Gemfile, you won't fine a place where you have a dependency or a define for the Rails constant.

Thus when you run the `backup` command and execute your db_backup.rb, the constant Rails called here is ... not defined. Ruby being kind will try to find a nested version of this constant in the current scope which is the `Model.new do; end` block.

It is still not defined which ruby tells you about with `NameError: uninitialized constant #<Class:#<Backup::Config::DSL:0x00007fb0db941d10>>::Rails`.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough and clear explanation.  Given the differences you describe, is there an approach you would recommend in this instance?  As described in my comments above, I ran into issues trying to create a rake file which calls the backup code - it doesn't know what `model` is since its defined outside of the Rails project.  In earlier versions of Rails, people have used `YAML load`, but when I've tried this I've returned `nil` when trying to call a particular value (I guess because the file is still encrypted?)

Comment: I did not have the occasion to use Rails builtin secrets mechanics yet. In previous versions i would have the secrets file registered in .gitignore to avoid versioning and would use deployment scripts for production

Answer (score 0):

@giglemad gives a great explanation of the issue of class resolution in the execution context (rails console vs. running of the backup ruby file).

To fix your error, just let the code know to use the top-level class lookup (`::Rails`):

```
Model.new(:db_backup, 'Description for db_backup') do
  ##
  # PostgreSQL [Database]
  #
  database PostgreSQL do |db|
    db.username = ::Rails.application.credentials.username
  end
end
```

If you're still seeing the missing Rails constant, you'll need to put your script in either a rake task,  or require your rails environment.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion on this.  Unfortunately this doesn't appear to resolve the issue in this case.  The suggested change causes the error message to become `NameError: uninitialized constant Rails` rather than `NameError: uninitialized constant #<Class:#<Backup::Config::DSL:0x00007fb0db941d10>>::Rails`

Comment: I updated my answer. If Rails still isn't defined, then you'll need to throw this in a rake task or require your environment manually

Comment: Thanks for your update.  When you say "require your environment manually", does this simply mean adding `require './config/environment'` to the top of `db_backup.rb` - this does seem to work (with `WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:`) and pulls information from `credentials.yml.enc` :).   In terms of putting this in a rake task, are you able to give an example (sorry for being slow).  I did create a rake where the task was simply `backup perform -t db_backup --config-file 'my_rails_app/config/Backup/config.rb'`, but I got the error `NameError: uninitialized constant Model`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the backup tool you're using. The rake task I'm thinking about would live in your Rails app and the code you have would live in there and require whatever library you're using for the backup. Since your using the code as a configuration file, this may not be ideal.